# Storing music ON/OFF state in preference-LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I have music button like this:

```
private void drawMusicButton() {
    musicButton = new ImageButton(new TextureRegionDrawable(musicTexture1),new TextureRegionDrawable(musicTexture2), new TextureRegionDrawable(musicTexture2));
    musicButton.setChecked(!game.menuMusicBool);
    stage.addActor(musicButton);

    musicButton.setPosition(UiConstants.MUSIC_X, UiConstants.MUSIC_Y, Align.bottom);
    musicButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            if (!game.buttonClickSoundBool&&game.soundBool)
                buttonClickSound.play();
            if (game.menuMusicBool)
                game.menuMusicBool = false;
            else
                game.menuMusicBool = true;
            musicStateManager.saveMusicState();
        }
    });
}
```

initially menuMusicBool is true.

```
public boolean menuMusicBool = true;
```

I want to store the music ON/OFF state in preference so that while relaunching the game,I can get the previously selected state.

My preference class is like this:

```
public class MusicStateManager {

  private final Preferences prefs;
  public final Mgame game;

  private static final String MUSIC_STATE = "musicState";

  public MusicStateManager(Mgame game){
      this.game = game;
      prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences(Mgame.class.getName());
  }

  public void getPreferenceValues(){ }

  public void reset(){ }

  public void saveMusicState() {

    prefs.putBoolean(MUSIC_STATE, game.menuMusicBool);
    prefs.flush();
  }

  public void getMusicState() {
     game.menuMusicBool = prefs.getBoolean(MUSIC_STATE);
  }
```

getMusicState() I am calling inside render().

But in preference,value is not getting stored properly.
I am not able to save the previous state while quitting and relaunching the game.

What I did wrong in the code?

Comment: no need to call `getMusicState()` inside `render()` method call once when game starts, it may be from `MusicStateManager` constructor

Comment: Also use unique name for your each App preference file name instead of `Mgame.class.getName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MusicStateManager {

  private final Preferences prefs;
  public final Mgame game;

  private static final String PREF_NAME ="APP_NAME";   
  private static final String MUSIC_STATE = "musicState";

  public MusicStateManager(Mgame game){
      this.game = game;
      prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences(PREF_NAME);
      game.menuMusicBool = prefs.getBoolean(MUSIC_STATE, true); // return true when key not found
  }

  public void saveMusicState(boolean musicState) {
    game.menuMusicBool = musicState;
    prefs.putBoolean(MUSIC_STATE, musicState);
    prefs.flush();

    // music state changed and saved, now need to start or stop music
    if(game.menuMusicBool)    // I supposed game having music object reference
         game.music.play();
    else 
         game.music.stop(); 
  }

  public boolean getMusicState() {
     return prefs.getBoolean(MUSIC_STATE);
  }
```

When you want to play music use `game.menuMusicBool` as flag

```
public void playMusic(Music music){

    if(game.menuMusicBool && !music.isPlaying()){
         music.play();
         music.setLooping(true);
     }
}
```

And Inside listener of musicButton

```
musicButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        if (!game.buttonClickSoundBool&&game.soundBool)
            buttonClickSound.play();
         musicStateManager.saveMusicState(!game.menuMusicBool);  // state inversed and saved in prefs
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.State is getting saved now.I tried this and working in an inverse way.For the first launch,music button has check mark and sound is not playing.Later everything works proper.

Comment: I am calling musicStateManager.getMusicState(); inside the menuscreen constructor.Is that okay?

Comment: no need to call `getMusicState();` I get music state in `MusicStateManager` constructor so when you create object of  `MusicStateManager` game.menuMusicBool value changed according to saved state.

Comment: Yes.right.I got confused on this because for other preference storage I used to call this get method in the class.It is working now!Thanks a lot!

Comment: make sure you're calling `game.menuMusicBool = prefs.getBoolean(MUSIC_STATE, true);` instead of `prefs.getBoolean(MUSIC_STATE);`